# How to convert a 2D object into a 1D stroke in inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, typography, tracing

I have a couple of edges in urdu I want to convert into strokes to make it more like handwriting. How can I convert a series of shapes into a stroke?

I tried taking a screenshot and using trace bitmap to do a centerline trace, but it wasn't as precise as I would like:

[image: Raw image]
[image: Vector shape by tracing edges]
[image: Stroke by using center line autotrace, but still not good enough. Its missing many of the dots and the strokes are disjointed]

The urdu script says "ingraizi" or "english".

Comment: You could try tweaking the options for the centerline tracing, to get a more detailed result. However, to me, the result looks quite good already. If you make the stroke wider, would it look better to you? I don't read Arabic / Urdu scripts, so I cannot really judge this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Central, simplified, "pen" strokes of a font glyph](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/72043/central-simplified-pen-strokes-of-a-font-glyph)

Answer (score 0):

This is the result I got by copy/pasting انگریزی into GIMP using the Text Tool with Sans font type, black font color and 48 font size.

[image]

Then I used the Shear Tool with Shear magnitude of X = 7 and Shear magnitude of Y = 0 to give it a slanted effect that looks more like handwriting. I also made it look more like handwriting by randomizing the spacing between the letters.

[image]

To save the resulting .png image as a vectorized image, open it in Inkscape and select the image -> select *Path* -> *Trace Bitmap* -> click the *OK* button, drag the vectorized image out of the canvas, delete the original .png image in the canvas, drag the vectorized image back into the empty canvas, and then select *File* -> *Save As…* and save it as SVG.

Comment: Thank you! I’ll try that technique, however it needs to be in a vector format. The reason is that I’m feeding in the vectorized result into a drawing machine to write it on a real piece of paper.