# Illustrator - Turning brush strokes into pencil strokes

Tags: adobe-illustrator, brush, pencil

I have a document with lots of drawing done with brush tool, however, when I tried to increase the stroke size it creates undesirable results with each stroke ending/corners rounded etc. I thought that I would be able to change the stroke settings to change the stroke caps and corners, but turns out you can't do that for brush tool?
Just now I've found the pencil tool and it creates exactly the result I want, and I can change the stroke settings as I wish which is perfect.
Is there any magic conversion method somewhere that would allow me to convert my brush stroke paths to pencil strokes?
Or do I have to redraw all of them? :/

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of depends on *which* brush is used.

If the brush strokes are *shapes with a fill* you are out of luck. There's no direct conversion back to a centerline path. There are [some tricks to try and work around to a centerline](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/72043/central-simplified-pen-strokes-of-a-font-glyph/72046#72046) again, but I suspect those may be more trouble than simply redrawing.

---

If the brush strokes ***are*** still merely stroked paths, just remove the brush stroke...

Select the paths, and in the **Brush Panel** click the **Basic** "brush". `Basic` isn't *really* a brush. It *really* means "basic path", i.e. no brush applied.

From that point you should have standard paths (like those you'd create with the Pencil Tool) where you can alter stroke weights, profiles, etc.

Comment: Thank you, it works! However now I have another problem, since I've used the reflection function to create my shapes, the center points aren't recognized as corners, but ends. Is there any way to convert the reflection to actual points and somehow merge the overlapping points? So that they are converted into corners.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/4GLGQ3T.png      Here is an image explaining that

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant I used the "Transform" effect under Effects > Distort & Transform > Transform, to create a copy of the drawing, and used the reflection checkboxes there to make a mirror reflection. I somehow need to turn that into real paths.

Comment: @AliEser That's really a different question and different issue entirely. Maybe post is as a new question.

Comment: @BillyKerr, thank I just did: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/144689/illustrator-converting-transform-effect-reflections-into-actual-paths